# How to download a big file in several simultaneous chunks and save them to the same file in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, file, download, chunks

I am using PyCurl, range http header and Python Threads, so if I need to download 1 gb file and want to use for example 5 connections to the server to speed the process up, I just divide 1 gb in five parts, and create five threads which download 1/5 per thread, save that 1/5 to a ".part" file, and when all the 5 threads are done and download its 1/5 file, I just join all the parts and recreate the 1 gb file.

My question is: how can I download the file in the same 5 chunks, but instead of save every chunk to a temp file and then join all the files into the original file, just download the 5 parts and save the parts to the a 1gb file directly? Is this possible?

Comment: So you already know how to download the parts in parallel and save to temp files? I'm assuming so since you mentioned you know that you can use PycURL and the Range HTTP header and described the process of how it works. But the process is the same, the only difference is you keep the chunks in memory instead of writing to separate files. So what's the problem?

Comment: @LampToast the problem is that for big files i cannot store the chunks in memory, imagine files over 10 gb.... so the process cant be the same....

Comment: in that case you probably can't do what you want. the parts have to be written to the file in the correct order. for example, if part 3 finishes downloading first you'll have to keep it in memory until you can finish downloading and writing parts 1 and 2. is there a reason you can't use temp files?

Comment: @LampToast not really, its just that if the user sees a lot of temp files may think that the program is  unprofessional, you can compare this behaviour with commercial download managers or event bittorrent, they download huge files and never use temp files (they create the file, and then "fill" it while download the parts, idk how), so that it should exist another approach to download a big file the way i want to do it....

Comment: @LampToast: this does not require anything being kept in memory. You can write to regions of a sparse file.

Comment: @martijinpieters I already covered that in my answer below

Answer (score 2):

So as we discussed in the comments, you can't *really* do what you're trying to do. There are a couple ideas I have in mind that might help you, though.

### Option 1

If you know the size of the file you're trying to download you could create a file of the needed size and overwrite with the bytes you download.

```py
with open("some_file_name", "wb") as f:
    f.truncate(some_size)
```

or

```py
with open("some_file_name", "wb") as f:
    f.seek(some_size - 1)
    f.write('\0')
```

*Note that if a specified size exceeds the file’s current size, the result is platform-dependent: possibilities include that the file may remain unchanged, increase to the specified size as if zero-filled, or increase to the specified size with undefined new content.*

so as you download parts you can overwrite the specific chunk of bytes with

```py
with open("some_file_name", "r+b") as f:
    f.seek(offset)
    f.write(data_chunk)
```

### Option 2

Decided how much memory you're willing to use and only download a certain number of parts in order at a time.

example: if you decided you only want to use 1GB and you want to download a large file in chunks of 250 MB

- Start downloading the first 4 chunks in parallel.
- When chunk 1 finishes downloading, you can write it to disk and start downloading chunk 5.
- if a chunk finishes downloading before a lower chunk (e.g. 2 finishes before 1) hold it in memory until the other chunk finishes
- this limits the memory usage to 1 GB because no more than four 250 MB chunks are downloading at once

### Option 3

write to temporary files (as you mentioned in your original question) but keep them in a location where the user probably won't see them such as your system's temp directory or in a hidden directory created by your program

Comment: On POSIX, there is no need to 'pre-create' the file. You can seek to any position and *just write*. The file can start out 'sparse', then fill out as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this easily, at least on a unix/linux system. The key is that you should create the file once in thread 1, opening it for writing. Then you need to *re-open* the file again N more times (also for write, but never for append) -- so that you get an independent file descriptor for each thread to use.

Next, have each thread `lseek` to the appropriate starting position within the file using its own file descriptor, and then it can begin writing chunks to the file as received from the server. (You should be able to use standard python file objects and their `seek` method too as long as you're using binary I/O.)

This works because each file descriptor has an independent file pointer, and on all unix systems, the file pointer should automatically advance as you write. Also, there is no problem with having gaps in the file; the OS should handle that fine.

IOW, for a 1GB file with 5 threads:

```
thread 1, fd 1, position 0 (writing through 200MB-1)
thread 2, fd 2, position 200MB (through 400MB-1)
...
thread 5, fd 5, position 800MB (through 1GB-1)
```

Code for a thread in python (assuming you've already created the file in the main thread) can be as simple as:

```
with open("the_file", "r+b") as myfile:   # open for update
    myfile.seek(my_starting_pos)
    while ...:
         next_chunk = recv_from_server()
         myfile.write(next_chunk)
```

Comment: `w` truncates the file, however. You'd have to open the file multiple times **before any writing take place**.

Comment: It might be better to use `'r+b'` for all threads but the initial one so you don't have to worry about when each thread opens the file for writing access. That mode lets you write without truncating.

Comment: Good point, @MartijnPieters. I'll update with your suggestion